# Name That... Name? 6

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I had a bad history in a post-II cold land

My meaning addresses lookers that just want to lend a hand

I helped bring Nazareth's most important into this place

Change the first letter in Tony for the LRA's face

Name that Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is

> Joseph

First line

> Joseph Stalin

Second line: no idea

Third line

> Joseph and Jesus

Fourth line

> Joseph Kony

Comment: Ohh, I think I was just typing the answer as sedrick posted his answer

Comment: The 2nd line refers to Jehovah's witnesses.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing it's

> Joseph

I had a bad history in a post-II cold land

> Joseph Stalin, post-WWII leader of Russia (cold place), possibly referring also to Cold War.

My meaning addresses lookers that just want to lend a hand

> Maybe something to do with the meaning of the name Joseph?

I helped bring Nazareth's most important into this place

> Joseph, foster father of Jesus (born in Nazareth)

Change the first letter in Tony for the LRA's face

> Joseph Kony, leader of Lord's Resistance Army (LRA) from Uganda

Comment: Darn, I need to up the difficulty if these name riddles are getting solved. See #5 in the series for a challenge like that. Good job!

Comment: @XavierStanton Yeah I actually checked the #5 before I saw this one. Seems quite tough. Great work with these name riddles though. I find them really interesting.

Comment: The big reason #5 is hard is because the name is really rare, research is definitely needed